# SQL read data?

Tags: iphone, sql, objective-c, sqlite

i used the code below to read the data from a file.sql nothing happen is there an issue ?

```
+ (void) getInitialDataToDisplay:(NSString *)dbPath {

SQLAppDelegate *appDelegate = (SQLAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

    const char *sql = "select coffeeID, coffeeName from coffee";
    sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
            Coffee *coffeeObj = [[Coffee alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];
            coffeeObj.CoffeeName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];

            coffeeObj.isDirty = NO;

            [appDelegate.coffeeArray addObject:coffeeObj];
            [coffeeObj release];
        }
    }
}
    else
        sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

appDelegate.m
    - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application{

```
[self copyDatabaseIfNeeded];
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.coffeeArray = tempArray;
[tempArray release];

[Coffee getInitialDataToDisplay:[self getDBPath]];
[window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

}

Comment: Are you sure that appDelegate.coffeeArray is not nil? Also, is sqlite3_open reporting an error? Is sqlite3_prepare_v2 reporting an error?

Comment: Use [FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does execution ever enter the while clause?

In addition to what has already been suggested, here are a few more things to try:

1) Launch your app on the simulator.  Open the database file using SQLite Database Browser ( http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net ) and verify the table exists.  Check the exact spelling of the table and column names.

2) Check that the database is opening the file and that dbPath is the correct path to the database file in the application's sandbox.  The path should be generated using the NSDocumentsDirectory:

```
 NSArray*  paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

3) Make sure you clean up all old statements properly with sqlite_finalize and close the database properly.  sqlite_close should not be in the "else" clause.

Comment: i followed all ur steps and also i can't see any extracted data from my database i will send my project to any one to fix this problem im really confused about this issue