# where to use SQLITE in iPhone apps?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, sqlite

I use the SQL with VB.net to make such Projects But Now Im learning and Looking to SQLITE in iPhone apps where can I use it for any exemple about an app used the sqlite or something like it

Comment: I'm confused.  It looks like you're already using SQLite within your application: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174268/sql-read-data.  Are you looking for a tutorial on how to do more?

Comment: No i Don't need data but in other platform than ios you can use Sql especially when u have a huge database maybe ios cant handle large database (im not a professional just an opinion)

Comment: @Bobi-C - Again, I don't really know what you're asking.  Of course you can use SQLite for data access on iOS, and it is very performant even for relatively large data sets.  Are you looking for where to use SQLite over other alternatives?

Comment: No All i need an example about app using sqlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQL Lite if you have to store larger amounts of data.
For a small amount of data is NSUserDefaults practicable.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the following thread on SO to get answer to your question.

[Where's the best SQLite 3 tutorial for iPhone-SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716839/wheres-the-best-sqlite3-tutorial-for-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to use *sqlite* - as opposed to using the *Core Data* framework?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html